# RecyclerView Offscreen Checkbox Data

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have a RecyclerView with checkboxes. I want that when the user checks or unchecks them, a database containing matching titles will update a boolean, depending on whether or not the checkbox is checked.

However, because there are a lot of checkboxes in this list, some of them are offscreen, and therefore aren't binded always.
When the user clicks OK to save his changes, I want to go through the list of checkboxes and check which ones are checked. But because not all of them are binded, some return null and I can't check them.

How do I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
OKButton.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(dbPath, null, DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadwrite);
            for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.ItemCount; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((mRecyclerView.FindViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as TimesSettingsAdapter.MyView).mTime.Checked)
                    {
                        string sql = "UPDATE Times SET Show = 'yes' WHERE Id = " + (i + 1).ToString();
                        db.ExecSQL(sql);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string sql = "UPDATE Times SET Show = 'no' WHERE Id = " + (i + 1).ToString();
                        db.ExecSQL(sql);

                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not create a separate key/column for every checked row and as soon as an item is checked update that key/column and when you have to check, check for this key/column was updated or not (setting it true/false would do)!!

Comment: @shadygoneinsane The problem is that I want to set it only when the user clicks OK, not when he checks it, because sometimes he want to cancel.

Comment: So update the key when Ok is pressed.. i don't see whats the problem here
Use the position of the element to map key value to it
Can you post your whole adapter code  here ..!!

Comment: @shadygoneinsane Yes, but the problem is that Once OK is pressed, I don't know hat all the values of thecheckboxes are, since some aren't binded and therefore return null.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, but the problem is that Once OK is pressed, I don't know hat all the values of thecheckboxes are, since some aren't binded and therefore return null.

I think you're right, `ViewHolder`s which holds your `CheckBox` cannot be retrieved when this item is Offscreen, it will get updated as soon as it gets scrolled in via `onBindViewHolder`

So, as a workaround, I think you can make a copy of your data when you read them from your database, and use this copy as the data resource of your `RecyclerView`, change the data of copy in Adapter when the `CheckBox`'s status is changed.

And finally when user press "OK" to save the changes, save the new copy of data to your database, and if user cancel it, use the original data to refresh the `RecyclerView`.

Or maybe you can find some other workarounds to solve your issue. Any further discussion, please leave a comment.